# Unable to figure out option filtering in React/ Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

Let me give you a little background about my requirement. Based on the value selected from the initial dropdown, that many dropdowns should be generated.I am able to achieve that. I have an array of options-which should be distributed euqally/near equally across the dropdowns. That is not happening. Any thing that I am missing ?

```
const KPI_OPTIONS = [
    "ABC",
    'DEF',
    'GHI',
    'JKL',
    'MNO'
];

const MAX_DROPDOWNS = 4;

const CustomAddModal = ({ open, onClose, createHandler, onOptionsSelected }) => {

    const [selectedDropdownCount, setSelectedDropdownCount] = useState('');
    const [dynamicDropdowns, setDynamicDropdowns] = useState([]);
    const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState(Array.from({ length: MAX_DROPDOWNS }, () => ''));

    console.log(selectedOptions);

    const handleCreate = () => {
        onOptionsSelected(selectedOptions);
        createHandler();
        setSelectedDropdownCount('');
        onClose();
    };

    const generateDynamicDropdowns = (count) => {
        const newDropdowns = Array.from({ length: parseInt(count) }, (_, index) => index + 1);
        setDynamicDropdowns(newDropdowns);
    };

    const handleOptionChange = (index, value) => {
        const newSelectedOptions = [...selectedOptions];
        newSelectedOptions[index] = value;
        setSelectedOptions(newSelectedOptions);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        generateDynamicDropdowns(selectedDropdownCount);
    }, [selectedDropdownCount]);

    return (
        <Modal
            open={open}
            closeAfterTransition
        >
            <Fade in={open}>
                <div style={{ ...modalStyle, width: '750px' }}>
                    <IconButton style={{ position: 'absolute', top: '10px', right: '10px', color: COLOR_WHITE }} onClick={onClose}>
                        <CloseIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                    <div style={{ color: COLOR_WHITE, textAlign: 'center' }}>Custom</div>
                    <div style={{ color: COLOR_WHITE }}>KPIs</div>
                    <div className="dropdown-container" style={dropdownContainerStyle}>
                        <Select
                            sx={selectStyle}
                            MenuProps={menuProps}
                            value={selectedDropdownCount}
                            onChange={(e) => setSelectedDropdownCount(e.target.value)}
                        >
                            <MenuItem sx={menuItemStyle} value="null">Select Option</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem sx={menuItemStyle} value="1">1</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem sx={menuItemStyle} value="2">2</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem sx={menuItemStyle} value="3">3</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem sx={menuItemStyle} value="4">4</MenuItem>
                        </Select>
                        {/* Render additional dropdowns based on the dynamicDropdowns array */}
                        {dynamicDropdowns.map((dropdown, index) => (
                            <Select
                                key={index}
                                sx={selectStyle}
                                MenuProps={menuProps}
                                value={selectedOptions[index]}
                                onChange={(e) => handleOptionChange(index, e.target.value)}
                            >
                                <MenuItem sx={menuItemStyle} value="">
                                    Select Option
                                </MenuItem>
                                {KPI_OPTIONS.map((option, optionIndex) => (
                                    <MenuItem key={optionIndex} sx={menuItemStyle} value={option}>
                                        {option}
                                    </MenuItem>
                                ))}
                            </Select>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                    <Button style={buttonStyle} onClick={handleCreate} variant="contained">
                        Create
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </Fade>
        </Modal>
    );
};
```

Comment: You're generating the same `KPI_OPTIONS` for all the dropdowns, which is why the options are not being distributed equally/near equally across the dropdowns.

Comment: better to create fiddle/codesandbox.